# Inherit multiple classes without multiple initialization in python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to design my code which has multiple class in a single python file such a way, Where class A is the Abstract class for classes `C()` and `D()`, Also class B is the Parent class for both classes `C()` and `D()`.

As you can see the I am using `super().__init__` to initialize the Abstract class and Parent class before executing any functionality in those classes.

The code is as follows:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running A.__init__')

    @abstractmethod
    def function(self):
        pass

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running B.__init__')


class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running C.__init__')
        # C.__init__()
        super(C, self).__init__()
        super(A,self).__init__()

    def function(self):
        pass

class D(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running D.__init__')
        super(D,self).__init__()
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def function(self):
        pass


foo = C()
bar = D()
```

**Output:**

```
Running C.__init__
Running A.__init__
Running B.__init__
Running D.__init__
Running A.__init__
Running B.__init__
```

Interested in learning how to avoid multiple initialization's , In simple words I want abstract class A and Parent class B Initialized before executing `C()` or `D()`, where C and D will have all functionalities inherited from A and B

```
foo = C()
bar = D()

Running A.__init__
Running B.__init__
Running C.__init__
Running D.__init__
```

I trying to learn OOPS concepts recently, Please help If Redesign the code is needed. Thank you

Comment: You don't initialize classes; you initialize *instances* of classes. You can't "share" the calls to `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` for the instances of `C` and `D`.

Comment: @chepner, Thank you, As you said I cant "share" the calls. Could you tell me how to design the code if there is better way than above code, If I have multiple classes E,F,G,H which inherit A and B.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the parent classes by running the `super().__init__()` before you run the initializer code in C or D.

C and D will still inherit the methods of A and B even if the initializer function is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure *everybody* is using `super`, not just `C` and `D`. That ensures that each class's `__init__` is called in the proper order. It gets more complicated if you start adding arguments to `__init__` in the child classes, because you don't know when you call `super().__init__()` just which class's method will be invoked next.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Running A.__init__')

    @abstractmethod
    def function(self):
        pass

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Running B.__init__')


class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running C.__init__')
        super().__init__()

    def function(self):
        pass

class D(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def function(self):
        pass


foo = C()
bar = D()
```

For example, the method resolution order for `C` is `[C, A, B, object]`. When you call `C()`, `C.__init__` gets called first. Its call to `super` causes `A.__init__` to be called next. The call to `super` in `A.__init__` does *not* go to `object`, the direct base class of `A`; it goes to `B.__init__`, because that's the next class after `A` in the MRO of the object (an instance of `C`) being initialized. Then, finally, `B.__init__` uses `super` to cause `object.__init__` to be called.